# вопрос про аргументы функции пхп

Tags: php

есть функция

```
function foo($arg = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')) {
//
}
```

возможно ли дополнить массив аргумента `$arg` не перечисляя заново элементы? то есть на подобии `foo($arg+(array('123'))` чтобы не перечислять `foo(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '123'));`

Comment: Ну а что тебе мешает просто изначально создать массив?

Comment: опишите задачу понятнее

Comment: @splash58 да куда тут понятнее. человек хочет добавить к массиву параметров по умолчанию одно значение

Comment: или он просто не знает про параметры по умолчанию. Или это два разных вызова....

Comment: @Alan, а вы можете изменить код функции, или это библиотечная функция?